# PHP Save selection from selection field to get database row

Tags: php, html, select, dropdown

I´m currently working on a dropdown which has three types an upper category, a category and an subcategory. The upper category must display the "oberkategorie" which you can see after id. Now I want that the category only display options which are part of the above selected upper category or have the same name like the selected upper category.

[Database Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4O9mk.png)

Hope you can understand what I mean.

Best regards

```
<select class="dropdown1"> Oberkategorie: 
<?php
  include "dbConn.php";  // Using database connection file here
  $records = mysqli_query($db,"select oberkategorie from dropdown");  // Use select query here 
  
  while($obk = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
  {
    echo "<option value='". $obk['oberkategorie'] ."'>" .$obk['oberkategorie'] ."</option>";  // displaying data in option menu
  }
?>
</select>  
<br><br>
<span>Kategorie: </span>
<br><br>
<select class="dropdown2"> Oberkategorie: 
<?php
  include "dbConn.php";  // Using database connection file here
  $records = mysqli_query($db,"select kategorie from dropdown");  // Use select query here 
  
  while($ktg = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
  {
    echo "<option value='". $ktg['kategorie'] ."'>" .$ktg['kategorie'] ."</option>";  // displaying data in option menu
  }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: _"Hope you can understand what I mean."_ - of course we do because this has basically been discussed _countless_ times before already. Go research keywords such as f.e. "dependent dropdowns php html js", and you should find plenty of explanations on how to do something like this.

Comment: Also, please go read [ask]. So far, you have not even managed to ask us an actual _question_, but only told us what you "want." The latter is never sufficient here on this site, we expect people to show some effort first of all.